# How would you find and get introduced to a patron in old Rome?

Tags: ancient-rome

As the question said, how would you get introduced to a Patron in old Rome?

Would you merely go to the Roman version of the town hall and inquire about which people were available as patrons and then show up at meeting hours and introduce your work and hope he would take you on?

Or was it it more of a "I know a guy, who knows a guy whose roommate´s uncle is friends with someone who knows of a patron and for 5 Aureus I will set the wheels in motion, to get you introduced to him and he MIGHT take you on as a client.

Or was patronage more about who you were, as in since your uncle was a general under Caesar Augustus, your uncle can use his connections and write you a letter of introduction to the family of Pompaius who will become your patron.
Basically unless you were someone or your family was, would you NEVER get introduced to a possible patron?

Comment: I don't know, but given that patronage is a zero sum game, it would make sense for clients to serve their patron by recruiting other potentially useful clients.  Patrons want the most useful clients, so they're going to send out clients to find other recruits.  While you might _want_ a patron, that doesn't matter; what matters is which patron wants you.

Comment: You could start by having a look at [Patronage in ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronage_in_ancient_Rome). Also, the OUP page [Roman Patronage](https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780195389661/obo-9780195389661-0309.xml) has some details and many useful references.

Comment: Idk, but - I'm a free, male, Roman citizen, so I have a marketable commodity - a **vote**. Patrons need votes, so - I find someone who will - invite me to dinner, help my son into a business or with my daughter's dowry. In return, he gets my vote. He gets another client to add to his retinue, showing how important /popular he is. Win-win.

Comment: You could always make yourself more attractive to your potential patron.  Not to mention that sheer mass of clients was considered desirable for a patron.

Comment: Some famous Romans (see Pompey) were so filthy rich, w/ so much land and random business around so many places, besides bossing over traditional gens / tribes and doing politics, that I do not even start to understand how they managed their business (trusted slaves? cousins / random gens members?  a good question?). I suppose their management were not always the most efficient possible. These guys had so many issues that there must have been many opportunities to be useful to them, the issue would be to be noticed among the cacophony of clan members and random sycophants

Comment: I don't have any sources at hand, but as far as I remember the system wasn't as much based on individuals but on families. Meaning, once you're born you typically become a client of your parent's patron. That doesn't cover all conceivable cases, but I'd think it covers the bulk.

Comment: @TheHonRose Your vote would not be that valuable, I think, because the voting in the centuriate assembly was so heavily skewed and biased towards the few top centuries that unless you were already rich and connected enough to be a member of them, it would not matter in practice. But a patron could always use another strong guy for his entourage/crowd of clackers/posse...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Yes, I know (a bit) about the skewed voting system, but I doubt any politician would turn away a potential supporter - apart from anything else, if Patron A chucks me out, I might sign up with Patron B, so lose-lose. And yes, a gaggle of togaed clients following you in the Forum was not to be sneezed at. Wasn't it largely about appearances?

Comment: For the most part you were born into it.  Whomever was your father's patron was now your patron.  In other cases, an entire city was under one patron because he originally conquered the city or maybe petitioned for the city to have latin rights or something to that effect.

Comment: "I know a guy, who knows a guy" - this is the short version of patronage.

Comment: By doing good work as a slave and convincing your owner to free you.  One of the motivations for emancipating slaves was that you instantly had more clients.

Comment: @CMonsour *freedmen* were a very specific group of clients, who couldn't "shop around" for a patron. I think the OP is asking about the Roman equivalent of "Joe Public".